# Prove that $\langle S\rangle$ $= G$, with $S \subset G$ and #$S > 1/p $ #$G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, prime-numbers, proof-writing

I'm having trouble with solving this problem:

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $> 1$, and $S \subset G$ a subset of $G$, with #$S > 1/p $ #$G$
Where p is the smallest prime factor of the order of G

Prove:
$\langle S\rangle$ (the generated set of $S)$ $= G$

I already proved the case $p = 2$, and I also proved that if $p = 2$, $\forall$ $g \in G: g = s_{1}s_{2}$ with $s_{1}, s_{2} \in S$. I don't know if that would help for this problem.

I've also done this:

$\langle S\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$, because $\langle S\rangle$ is not empty(trivial) and, given $s_{1}, s_{2} \in \langle S\rangle$, $s_{1}^{-1}s_{2} \in \langle S\rangle$
Now that $\langle S\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$, we know that $\#\langle S\rangle \mid \#G$.

I don't know how to finish the prove know. Could you help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't use `<S>`. The correct way is `\langle S\rangle`. Also, do not use constructions like `$x \in$ $X$`. There's no need for that extra space in the middle. TeX (okay, MathJax) takes care of correct spacing if you just write `$x \in X$. See my edits for more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that $\def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}S \subseteq \<S>$, hence 
$$ \# \<S> \ge \# S > \frac 1p \# G$$
Write $\# G = \#\<S> \cdot k$, then 
$$ \# \<S> > \frac kp \#\<S> $$
or $k < p$. As $k$ is a divisor of $\# G$ and $p$ its smallest prime factor, $k = 1$. Hence $\# G = \#\<S>$ and therefore $\<S> = G$.

Comment: Thank you! your answer is clear and understandable!

Comment: A much briefer way of saying the same thing: Every proper subgroup of $G$ has order at most $\frac{1}{p}|G|$. $\langle S\rangle$ is a subgroup with more generators.